# Display multiple field of Datashape

Tags: visio

I am creating some new set of figures in Visio 2019 Pro, and I would like to parametrize the various pieces of information to be displaid via data shape.

Example : I would like to create a box that have 2 data shapes : name & size.
And I would like to display the name at the center of the box and the size just below the box.
I have failed to display 2 different fields : I can only display one.
And I do not know how to position a field at a specific location (in y example, I do not know how to force the size to be just below the box).

Is this possible in Visio ?